# Will compiler give any error if we use malloc in bootloader code?

Tags: c, memory-management

As **Bootloader** comes before **kernel** is up and according to my understanding we *cannot* use malloc before **kernel** is up.

Comment: I think you can answer this empirically...

Comment: It all depends on whether the boot loader designer decide to link to a standard library that provides malloc, or not. Like in u-boot code there are a lot of malloc calls. http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git&a=search&h=HEAD&st=grep&s=malloc

Comment: After reading your comment, I got another query, If the bootloader does not link to a standard library, then how the memory available will be divided (Like how the stack space will be created)? Thanks!

Comment: @NitishKhatri That's up to your bootloader to decide.

Comment: As per my knowledge, when code jumps from **rom code** to **bootloader** at that time before executing the bootloader(main), its stack and other memory regions are made.

Answer (score 2):

The bootloader needs to be self-contained, so can't use *anything* not present in the bootloader.  This means that you generally<sup>1</sup> don't link the bootloader with any libraries, and if you try to use anything defined in a library you don't link with, you'll get a linking error.

---

<sup>1</sup> You might use (and link with) a static "bare-metal" support library, which could conceivably contain memory management support.